# LU decomposition 2x2 matrix restrictions?

Tags: numerical-methods, lu-decomposition

Wikipedia states that:
If matrix A is invertible, then it admits an LU (or LDU) factorization if and only if all its leading principal minors are nonzero.

However matrix \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix} 
has leading principal minors:
 M1 = 0 and M2 = -1 and this matrix has LU factorization:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}
When I made a mistake using this logic?

Comment: that product doesn't equal $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$!

Comment: Ah i see now I was mistaken by calculator which gave answer PA = LU